# render partial view recursively in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I'm new to ruby on rails and I'm facing a problem rendering nested questions.

What I want to achieve is rendering the question and check if it have children question then render the children questions as well.
there is no limit on the nesting levels, so I have to use recursion method to achieve this and this is what I came up with.

```
# view file code
<% @questions.each do |q| %>

    <%= render partial: "shared/question_block", locals: {q: q} %>

    <% if have_children_questions?(q.id) == 'true' %>

            <%= print_children_questions( get_children_ids(q.id) ) %>

    <% end %>

<% end %>
```

and here is the helper functions I created

```
def have_children_questions?(id)
    children = Question.get_children(id)
    if !children.empty?
        'true'
    else
        'false'
    end
end

def get_children_ids(id)
    ids = Question.where(parent: id).pluck(:id)
end

def print_children_questions(ids)
    ids.each do |id|
        q = Question.find(id)
        render partial: "shared/question_block", locals: {q: q}
        if have_children_questions?(id)
            print_children_questions( get_children_ids(id) )
        end
    end
end
```

print_children_questions method returning the ids instead of the partial view, what I'm doing wrong?
is there is a better solution

Thanks in advance